# Parabolic projectile motion with friction

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I want to analyze the projectile motion when throwing a ball under an angle with air friction.

Now Ive got the thow ODEs:

$$y''(t)-\frac{b}{m}y'(t)=-g$$ and $$x''(t)-\frac{b}{m}x'(t)=0$$

I have 
$y(t)=\frac{c_1}{k}e^{kt}+\frac{gt}{k}+c_2$ and $x(t)=\frac{c_3}{k}e^{kt}+c_4$ as solutions.

But after determining the $c_i$ and solving $x(t)$ for $t$ I become a function $y(x)$ which is increasing.
My problem is now that $y(x)$ clearly doesnt describe the projectile motion of a thrown object. Why is that? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation comes from Newton's second law, $F=ma$. You should write it in the form

$$my''(t)=-g-by'(t)$$

where the left side is $ma$ and the right side is the force. You have implicitly defined negative to mean down (by the sign on your $g$, and thus up is positive. Well, when the ball is moving up, the air resistance pushes it down, not up. And when the ball is moving down, the air resistance is pushing it up. Your formula showed the opposite. Your first equation should read

$$y''(t)+\frac{b}{m}y'(t)=-g$$

You might also reconsider your work with $x(t)$, as it might make more sense to you to define the motion to be in the positive direction. Then you expect $x''(t)<0$, so you might wish to write $x''(t)=-\frac{b}{m}x'(t)$, but this is not necessary as your equation will still work. Your formatting might be counter-intuitive to yourself, but is not inherently incorrect.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much! So that means, that my formula for $y$ is right for the second part when the object is falling towards the ground again?

Comment: @TwoStones when the object begins to fall down, the sign on $y'(t)$ switches, so the formula that I have provided is consistent all the way through.

Comment: and can you maybe also tell me on how to then plot the trajectory? Thats my actual goal

Comment: @TwoStones Solve the system for $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ with initial conditions. For a $45^{\circ}$ launch angle, you might choose $y(0)=x(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=x'(0)=1$. Then, on desmos type in ({equation for $x$ in terms of $t$}, {equation for $y$ in terms of $t$}), omitting the braces. For example, if I omit the air resistance, and set the mass of the object equal to a value such that $g/m=1$, then $\left(t,\ -\frac{t^2}{2}+t\right)$ plots the parabolic trajectory.